# dynamic document root in vhost.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp, virtualhost, vhosts

I want to make a subdomain for every teammember on a localserver (windows, wamp) in wich they can create folders which are seperate websites.

for example:

```
member1.local.dev/projectx/
member2.local.dev/projecty/
member2.local.dev/projectz/
```

But i can't get the document root display correcty. I don't want adjust the document root for every website in a .htaccess, but i want to fix it in the vhost.conf.

I found [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.htm), but if i am trying to implement it i get a 403 forbidden.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName local.dev
    ServerAlias member1.local.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot "c:\httpdocs\member1\%2"
    DocumentRoot "c:\httpdocs\member1\%2"
    <directory "c:\httpdocs\member1\%2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am i doing wrong, can somebody give me a kick in the right direction?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Sush: I did not, switched to creating a virtual host for every project and using tools like https://ngrok.com to share local urls to the team.